# Remove Spaces From List of Lists in Racket

Tags: list, recursion, formatting, racket, conjunctive-normal-form

I'm working on a PL logic resolver, and I need to make sure the input either has no spaces, or evenly spaced.  I think removing the spaces will be easier.  So I'm writing a function that removes the spaces from an input.

So far I have:

```
;sample input
(define KB&!alpha
  '((Girl)
    (~ Boy)
    (~~Boy)
    ( ~(FirstGrade ^ ~ ~ Girl))
    (Boy / Child)))

(define formatted null)

;formatting function
(define (Format_Spaces KB&!alpha)
  (for/list ((item KB&!alpha))
    (cond 
      ((list? item)(Format_Spaces item))
      ((not (eq? item " "))(set! formatted (append formatted (list item))))
      ((eq? item " ")(Format_Spaces (cdr KB&!alpha)))
    )
  )
)
```

But it's clearly giving me the wrong output.

Not only are the spaces still there, the output is a weird combination of the input.  Can anybody help me out on this?

I want to get something like this:

```
'((FirstGrade)
    (FirstGrade=>Child)
    (Child^Male=>Boy)
    (Kindergarten=>Child)
    (Child^Female=>Girl)
    (Female)))
```

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:  I'm trying to make the input uniform in format. In the new sample input, (~ Boy) is parsed as 2 symbols, (~~Boy) as 1 symbol, and (~ ~ Girl) as 3.  I think this will be difficult to parse.  Especially with different variations of symbols/operators/spaces.  (ie. is "Child^" to be parsed as "Child","^" or as "Child^" a whole symbol?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RE-EDIT:

Based on the comments you've made below, it looks to me like you're actually going to be writing this algorithm in Racket.

In that case, I have a *much* simpler prescription for you: Don't Do Anything. In particular, your input doesn't currently contain any spaces at all. The spaces you see are being inserted as part of Racket's display mechanism, in much the same way that a database printer might print fields separated with commas or tabs.

Rather than worrying about the commas, focus on the resolution algorithm. What does it take, and what does it produce?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to remove that (display) it was just to help me check my output while debugging.  I've removed it now.  I've also added the sample input.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply.  The overarching goal is to write a Racket implementation of the PL-Resolution algorithm.  I am trying to convert the logical statement (KB AND NOTalpha) into CNF so I can pass that into a loop that checks for empty clauses and recurs as needed.  I believe that each of those propositional logic sentences (output lines) should be in its own brackets so I can check is any sentence (clause?) is empty.  The input data, KB, may be defined with odd spacing that may throw off the parsing while converting to CNF, which I why I am trying to remove the spaces.

Comment: I cleared up my question a bit.  Note the new sample input and the "EDIT:".  I wonder if you can help?

Comment: Can you share more about the framework for this problem? Where do the inputs come from?